# How to change email header Odoo 10

Tags: configuration, odoo, odoo-10, erp

[image]

I'm trying to change the pink header at the top ( color and text ) 
in Configuration i've found only how to change content
any idea !!

Answer (score 2):

Follow this step :

- login Odoo
- Activate debug mode
- Go to Setting menu
- Open Email menu
- Select Templates
- Search sale order template
- Edit template